# Partially override prototype?

Tags: javascript, dom, fabricjs, dom-events

Is there anyway to partially override a prototype?

I am using fabricjs and want to override the `onKeyDown` event for the `Textbox` class. The goal is to have a different `Enter` key behaviour than default one.

I've tried this approach

```
fabric.Textbox.prototype.onKeyDown = (function(onKeyDown) {
    return function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 46) console.log('blur');
        // else super(e); <== default behavior would be appreciated here

        onKeyDown.call(this, e);
    }
})(fabric.Textbox.prototype.onKeyDown);
```

The result was the `Enter` key was only working, and the already existing functionality implemented by the fabric dev/team is lost. I want the `onKeyDown` to work as its supposed to out-of-the-box but instead of the default fabric's `Enter` behavior, I want my custom `Enter` key behavior for the mentioned event.

Comment: And what's the result of your attempt?

Comment: @Utkanos Sorry forgot to mention it, I've added it to question description!

Comment: To stop default key press behaviour use e.preventDefault() and then write your custom code. And I think keyCode for "Enter" key is 13 not 46.

Comment: @RK_15 Great idea! Let me try that! (slaps himself for thinking this xD). Oh yeah, my bad, I copied the delete keycode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your keycode to [keysMap](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Textbox.html#keysMap) and assign your method.

***DEMO***

```js
fabric.Textbox.prototype.keysMap[13] = 'onEnterKeyPressed';

fabric.Textbox.prototype.onEnterKeyPressed = function(e){
  console.log('enter key pressed')
}

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var textbox = new fabric.Textbox('FABRICJS')
canvas.add(textbox)
```

```css
canvas{
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.6.0/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='c' width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this would work:

```
// cache original function
const stockKeyDown = fabric.Textbox.prototype.onKeyDown

// override prototype
fabric.Textbox.prototype.onKeyDown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 46) {
    console.log('blur')
    return
  }

  // call cached version
  stockKeyDown.call(this, e)
}
```